# Is this Stored Procedure is safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

Can anyone tell me, is this stored procedure safe from SQL injection?

I am using 3 tier architecture and only sending the required parameters for insert, update and delete action.

If this is not safe from SQL injection then how can I make it secure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStudent]
    @parmID int = null,
    @parmName varchar(50) = null,
    @parmClass int = null,
    @parmSection varchar(1) = null,
    @parmYear varchar(15) = null,
    @parmIsActive bit = null,
    @parmAction varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
    begin
        if @parmAction = 'insert'
            insert into tblStudent 
            values (@parmName, @parmClass, @parmSection, @parmYear, @parmIsActive)
    end

    begin
        if @parmAction = 'update'
            update tblStudent 
            set StdName = @parmName, 
                ClassID = @parmClass, 
                Section = @parmSection, 
                Year = @parmYear, 
                IsActive = @parmIsActive 
            where StdID = @parmID
    end

    begin
        if @parmAction = 'delete'
            delete from tblStudent 
            where StdID = @parmID
    end
END
```

Comment: Why would you have a generic stored procedure that takes in the action type?  You should have seperate sprocs for insert / update / delete to make your life easier.  Think about what happens when you start building upon this, this could be a nightmare to maintain.  Saying something does not suffer from some sort of hack is risky, almost anything can be hacked.  It appears you are using parameters to pass to the sproc and this data is somehow validated back on the client / server side than no you wont have a sql injection.  But you need to seperate this out.

Comment: I agree with JonH. That doesn't make any sense

Comment: StoredProcedure are all a nightmare to maintain. For simple queries like those above a datalayer in your program is more than enough (warning: opionions, opinions)

Comment: Think about this, what if the @parmAction type is 'delete'.  In this case passing the other parameters aside from the `@parmID` makes no sense whatsoever.  This only works because you've essentially nullified them / set them to some default values.  This can be confusing to other developers.

Comment: SQL Server will also only cache one execution plan, while there are three executions that could happen.  This is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is perfectly safe from SQL Injection.
As long as you have parameterized every value, it is safe.

However, as also stated by JonH, your stored procedure doesn't make much (if any) sense. It will probably end up in a maintenance nightmare.

IMHO, you shouldn't be using stored procedures at all for simple inserts / updates / deletes.